# How to programatically open a ToolStripMenu as if I have hovered my mouse over it?

Tags: c#, winforms

If the title doesn't make sense, I have a ToolStripMenu with a number of ToolStripMenuItems inside it. Is there a way for me to create a hotkey (eg Ctrl + G) such that clicking this combination of buttons opens the ToolStripMenu to be viewed to the user?

If that's possible, would I also be able to do a similar thing to a ToolStripMenu within a ToolStripMenu? For example, of I have a menu as an item in another menu and click Ctrl + G, the interior menu displays (at an arbitrary location, say at the cursor position, for this example it doesn't matter).

Comment: Prefix one letter of the ToolStripMenuItems Text with &. When the user now presses ALT and then that letter (key) the menu opens. Thats how the standard works

Comment: That works exactly as I wanted, however that seems to only work in the first case, where the ToolStripMenu is directly within the form you alt + [key] in. Is it possible to use a similar method to have an interior ToolStripMenu be displayed? I attempted something similar to:
"&MamaMenu" -> "&ChildMenu" -> Options
Clicking Alt + M shows the MamaMenu, clicking Alt + M + C shows the MamaMenu and ChildMenu, but Alt + C does nothing.